EF Core doesn't stop tracking foreign key list item
Trying to edit an office entity and this works great for everything, except when the editedOffice passes less salesPerson ID's then there were before. If there are less id's it should remove them from the list inside the db as well, currently it's not doing that. It is however adding new ones correctly when you pass more ids that weren't there before.
public async Task<OfficeDTO?> EditOfficeAsync(OfficeEditDTO editedOffice)
{
    var office = await dbContext.Offices.Include(o => o.Address)
                                         .Include(o => o.SalesPeople)
                                         .FirstOrDefaultAsync(o => o.Id == editedOffice.Id);

    if (office == null)
        return null;

    var selectedSalesPeopleIds = office.SalesPeople.Select(o => o.Id).ToList();


    if (editedOffice.Name != null)
        office.Name = editedOffice.Name;

    if(editedOffice.Address != null)
    {
        if (editedOffice.Address.AddressLine != null)
            office.Address.AddressLine = editedOffice.Address.AddressLine;

        if (editedOffice.Address.PostalCode != null)
            office.Address.PostalCode = editedOffice.Address.PostalCode;

        if (editedOffice.Address.City != null)
            office.Address.City = editedOffice.Address.City;

        if (editedOffice.Address.Country != null)
            office.Address.Country = editedOffice.Address.Country;
    }

    

    if (!new HashSet<int>(editedOffice.SalesPeopleIds).SetEquals(selectedSalesPeopleIds))
        office.ReplaceSalesPeople(await dbContext.SalesPeople.Where(s => editedOffice.SalesPeopleIds.Contains(s.Id)).ToListAsync());


    await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();


    return new OfficeDTO(
        office.Id,
        office.Name,
        new AddressDTO(
            office.Address.Id,
            office.Address.AddressLine,
            office.Address.PostalCode,
            office.Address.City,
            office.Address.Country
        ),
        office.SalesPeople.Select(s => new SalesPersonDTO(s.Id, s.Name)).ToList()
    );
}

In office:
private List<SalesPerson> _salesPeople = [];

public IReadOnlyCollection<SalesPerson> SalesPeople
{
    get => _salesPeople.AsReadOnly();
    init => _salesPeople = Guard.Against.NoDuplicatesAndNotNull(value).ToList();
}

public void ReplaceSalesPeople(IEnumerable<SalesPerson> salesPeople)
{
    Guard.Against.NoDuplicatesAndNotNull(salesPeople);

    _salesPeople.Clear();
    _salesPeople.AddRange(salesPeople);

}

I even tried to set them to null and that doesn't work?
public void ReplaceSalesPeople(IEnumerable<SalesPerson> salesPeople)
{
    Guard.Against.NoDuplicatesAndNotNull(salesPeople);


    var salesPeopleToRemove = _salesPeople.Where(s => !salesPeople.Any(ns => ns.Id == s.Id)).ToList();

    foreach (var salesPerson in salesPeopleToRemove)
    {
        salesPerson.Office = null;
    }
    _salesPeople.Clear();
    _salesPeople.AddRange(salesPeople);
    
}

What can I do to make EF Core correctly track/dissassociate the Relation between office and salesperson?

In general, replacement isn't a good idea. AFAIK Clear() can be used to remove all items from a one-to-many collection, but overall when updating a collection you should avoid Clear() and absolutely not reinitialize the collection. So on that front your approach is good. Something like _salesPeople = salesPeople was the first "Gotcha" I was looking for. I believe your code for the most part should have worked, but two things come to mind. The use of the ReadOnlyCollection and the use of Clear().
Your read only collection implementation might have some issues depending if this is EF Core 9 or an earlier version. For EF Core 9 there were some changes to automatically detect and handle IReadOnlyCollection and backing fields. In this case the property/field should be simplified to:
private List<SalesPerson> _salesPeople = [];
public IReadOnlyCollection<SalesPerson> SalesPeople => _salesPeople;

IF this is EF Core 8 or earlier then EF should be configured to explicitly use the backing field _salesPeople. Since you are modifying the backing field, if EF is using the SalesPeople property for the tracking collection (Even though it is a ReadOnlyCollection it may not detect changes made to the backing field unless that is explicitly configured. EF Core can detect backing fields, but sometimes code in the getters/setters can interfere with that.
There may be an issue with the Clear() approach. An alternate approach:
var office = await dbContext.Offices.Include(o => o.Address)
                                         .Include(o => o.SalesPeople)
                                         .FirstOrDefaultAsync(o => o.Id == editedOffice.Id);

if (office == null) // is this a valid scenario? If not, just use `.SingleAsync()` and have the exception handled and 500/404 returned.
    return null;

var selectedSalesPeopleIds = office.SalesPeople.Select(o => o.Id).ToList();

// ...

var salesPeopleIdsToRemove = selectedSalesPeopleIds.Except(editedOffice.SalesPeopleIds);
var salesPeopleIdsToAdd = editedOffice.SalesPeopleIds.Except(selectedSalesPeopleIds);

if(salesPeopleIdsToRemove.Any())
    editedOffice.RemoveSalesPeopleById(salesPeopleIdsToRemove);
if(salesPeopleIdsToAdd.Any())
{
    var salesPeopleToAdd = await dbContext.SalesPeople
        .Where(x => salesPeopleIdsToAdd.Contains(x.Id))
        .ToListAsync();
    editedOffice.AddSalesPeople(salesPeopleToAdd);
}
await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

From this it should be easy to work out how ""RemoveSalesPeopleById()" and "AddSalesPeople()" work. You shouldn't need to explicitly set/clear the SalesPerson.Office in either case. Alternatively the Remove can accept entities, being something like office.RemoveSalesPeople(office.SalesPeople.Where(x => salesPeopleIdsToRemove.Contains(x.Id))); I passed the Ids rather than entities as "Remove" should only be referencing entities associated to the Office, where such a method could be passed an arbitrary set so the method should be asserting to only remove items associated with that office in any case. "AddSalesPeople" should assert only items not already in the collection are added.
Replacing collections can get "ugly" as EF doesn't like scenarios where an item is marked to be removed from a collection where the same item is also supposed to be marked as added to the collection. Your approach does look like it should still work, but may be falling foul of the change tracker. The extra advantage of the above approach is in the case of adding any new associations, or simply removing associations, only the items that need to be added are fetched from the DbContext rather than the complete updated set each time.
